# Making an element in reverse side using css

Tags: html, css

I want to make an element inside html to be displayed in reverse side or direction including images and text. See the image [image: normal]

I expect to have as an example:
[image: after]

Comment: This is not a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Esmatullah Arifi Please add the relevant code what you had tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css `tranform` option
[demo](https://jsbin.com/jedafoyucu/edit?html,output) or see following snippet.

```css
.flip {
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

```html
<p class="flip"> translation</p>
```

Comment: Demo should be included into answer itself.

Comment: Upvoted for answering faster than me. :D

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="reversed">Translate</div>
```

CSS:

```
#reversed {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Alternative:

```
#reversed {
    transform: scale(-1,1);
}
```